# Github: git submodule update hangs, does not clone

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I run, on linux:

```
git clone https:// ... /my_project.git
cd my_project
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

And it updates fine.

I run, on mac:

```
git clone https://.../my_project.git
cd my_project
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

And it hangs indefinitely.

Then I check out the same modules as stand alone projects:

```
git clone https://.../the_submodule.git
```

And I get a normal clone.

I see this issue pop up a lot, but there seems to be no clear answer.  Git does not fail to clone with any error message during submodule update, it just tries for a few minutes, clones nothing, and moves on to the next submodule.

Comment: This seems a bug with the "git" client on mac. Try some debugging tool to try to discover where is blocked. For example, "strace" is a good option. Using it, you can see the list of syscalls and open files.